# Understanding how parameters work in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Here is a sample code from a RSpec code:

```ruby
describe Thing do
  def create_thing(options)
    thing = Thing.new
    thing.set_status(options[:status])
    thing
  end

  it "should do something when ok" do
    thing = create_thing(:status => 'ok')
    thing.do_fancy_stuff(1, true, :move => 'left', :obstacles => nil)
    ...
  end
end
```

So my confusion is mostly on this line:

```
thing.set_status(options[:status])
```

So create_thing method has an "option" parameter then we are passing status part of that parameter? Can someone explain this syntax in some easier words?

Comment: Please post text, not images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`options` is just a variable. The part you need to understand is this part

```
thing = create_thing(:status => 'ok')
```

You are basically passing a `Hash` to create_thing and therefore `options` is a hash. Then you can access the value of the `status` key by doing `options[:status]`.

If the above mentioned line looked like this

```
thing = create_thing("Foo")
```

`options` would be "Foo" and you could get an error trying to do something like `options[:status]`

Answer (score 2):

`create_thing` takes an argument called `options`.

Options is expected to be a hash (most likely).

You're passing the hash value with the key (a symbol)`:option` to the `set_status` method.

You've *passed* an implicit hash to `create_thing`:

`create_thing({ status: 'ok' })` is the same as 
`create_thing(status: 'ok')` is the same as 
`create_thing(:status => 'ok')`

Any way you call it, you *access* that value via `options[:status]`.